# Existence and uniqueness of the solution of the Ordinary Differential Equation, $y'+p(x)y(x)=q(x)$ where $x\in[a,b)$ and $y(b)$ is known.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Existence and uniqueness of the solution of the Ordinary Differential Equation, $$y'+p(x)y(x)=q(x)$$ where $x \epsilon[a,b)$ and $y(b)$ is known.

Can someone please direct me how to proceed. I have been asked by my teacher to do a seminar on this question and this is a completely new concept/topic for me.

I searched online for answers but could not get a proper explanation. Can someone please provide links or explain here how to proceed.

What I found online is Picard's Theorem but it needs an initial condition whereas I am given $y(b)$.
Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is a linear differential equation, and there is a well-known method of solution. I would suggest a careful analysis of this method.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you please provide some links/hints where I can start.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [this](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/gnagy/teaching/ode.pdf) as a reference. The existence of $y'=a(t)y+b(t)$ is discussed page $12$ onwards.